# Sitecore 8 - updating bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, sitecore, bootstrap-4

Very short question - does anyone know how to update Bootstrap in Sitecore 8?

Seems my version is running 3.3.7.

Many thanks.

Comment: You'll need to also re-write the HTML if you're upgrading to Bootstrap 4. You can't just import Bootstrap v3 HTML to Bootstrap v4

Comment: Sitecore is a framework and does not use Bootstrap or provide components OOTB (unless you're using SXA) - this is an implementation detail and updating will vary project to project.

Comment: @jammykam - ok so no easy documented method to do this? I'm wondering if it's worth it now as don't want to mess up Sitecore. And we are using SXA.

Comment: I haven't used SXA i'm afraid. You might also want to update your question with which version of Sitecore and SXA you are using, it _might_ make a difference but definitely the fact you are using SXA makes a difference.